# How to Fix Expo App by removing location services

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

At the moment play store says "Remove the request for location permissions from your app" but I am not using location services anywhere in the app at the moment.

I am already set the "permissions": [] in app.json file.

app.json

```
"android": {
      "package": "com.xxxx",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "permissions": [],
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete node_modules
2. Delete package-json.lock
3. Reinstall all: npm install

Source: https://forums.expo.io/t/remove-the-request-for-location-permissions-from-your-app/41488/50